# Whats wrong on this CSS? that does not goes 100% when more content is added?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns and they work just fine, the problem is that when I add more content it stays the same and the columns just don't align properly.

This is without too much content:
http://clients.latamig.com/genomalab/index.html

Now when I add more content it looks like this: http://clients.latamig.com/genomalab/index2.html

I'd like a CSS solution. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Think about your height value.  100%.  100% of what?

When you put a width value of 100%, what is it 100% of?  the content in the container?  or the container that the element is in?

Comment: @WouterJ not a duplicate of the question you are linking to

Comment: added a demo link to my solution below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to post your relevant css and html. 
There are a few possible solutions. You can set a min-height for your container. And allow it to expand to a set max-height. You could set an overflow-y value of auto for the container to allow the user to scroll down to view the extra content...

```
#yourContainer{
    min-height:800px;
    max-height:1200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

here's an example pen - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/KqAfG

Comment: lukeocom thank you. you've saved my life :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove your `height: 100%`
It is 100% of the window, not the document.

Instead put `min-height: 100%`

Comment: I fixed that. But now the menu wont go 100% full height. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: IF you see the site again the index2.html you will see what i mean.

Comment: Hum good question, I don't know if there is a CSS solution. You can try a little hack by setting the background color to your .wrapper. And by changing little things to make it clean

Comment: Or also add a wrapper for your two columns to set background on this div

Comment: By the way i used it on my design and its perfect, the problem is that on IE it just does not work :( any ideas how to make it look properly like on Google Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

you should give a solution of `max-height: 00px;` in CSS.
It would always give the same height, no matter what

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `min-height 100%` and the `max-height auto;`